# simple speech recognition methods

Tags: neural-network, speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models

Yes, I'm aware that speech recognition is fairly complicated (as an understatement). What I'm looking for is a method for distinguishing between *maybe* 20-30 phrases. An ability to split words (discrete speech is fine) would be nice, but isn't required. The software will be user-dependent(i.e. for use by me). I'm not looking for existing software, but for a good way of going about doing this myself. I've looked into various existing methods and it seems like splitting the sound into phonemes, while common, is somewhat excessive for my needs.

For some context, I'm just looking for a way to control some aspects of my computer with a few simple voice commands. I'm aware that Windows already has speech recognition software, but I'd like to go about this one myself as a learning exercise. Commands would be simple like "Open Google", or "Mute". What I had in mind (not sure if this is a good idea) is that some commands would be compound. So "Mute" would just be "Mute". Whereas the "Open" command could be recognized individually, and then have its suffixes (Google, Photoshop, etc). recognized with another network/model/whatever. But I'm not sure if looking for prefixes/word breaks in this way would produce better results than having to deal with an increased number of individual commands.

I've been looking into perceptrons, hopfield networks (though they're somewhat obsolete from what I understand) and HMMs, and while I understand the ideas behind these (I've implemented the ANNs before) I don't really know which is best suited to this task. I'm assuming that linear vector quantization models would also be appropriate, but I can't really find much literature to this end. Any guidance/resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago, I read a whitepaper about a limited vocabulary system, which used a simple recognition process.  The system divided each utterance into a small number of bins (6 in time, and 4 in magnitude, if I remember correctly, for 24 total), and all it did was count the number of sample audio measurements in each bin.  There was a fuzzy logic rule base which then interpreted each utterances 24 bin counts, and generated an interpretation.

I imagine that (for some applications) a simple matching process might work just as well, in which the 24 bin counts of the current utterance are simple matched against those of each of your stored prototypes, and the one with the least overall difference is the winner.

Answer (score 3):

There are some open source project in speech recognition:

1. HTK (Hidden Markov Models Toolkit)
2. Sphinx

Both have decoder, training, language model toolkits. Eveything to build a complete and robust speech recognizer.
Voxforge has acoustic and language models for both open source speech recognition toolkits.